# How do I select one of 5 child elements which has a unique class name in XPath?

Tags: html, css, xpath

In the linked screenshot below, it's a rating out of 5. If a 1 star rating is given by the user. The HTML looks like this:.

[image]

However, if let's say a four star rating is given the HTML looks like this:

[image]

I want to get the user rating so "1" or "4" repsctively in the screenhots above.

So far I have got this:

```
.//td[@class='review-rating-header seat_comfort']/following-sibling::td[@class='review-rating-stars stars']//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' fill ')]
```

This selects "1" for all rows even though user ratings maybe "2", "3", "4" or "5".

I'm web scraping by the way, if that helps.

Any ideas on how to get desired XPath element?

Comment: The highlighted element contains the text "1" and your expression returns "1". What's your actual problem?

Comment: It returns "1" for all rows, even though "star fill" may be a "2", "3" or etc. It doesn't get the class which has star fill in automatically. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last `span` with class `fill`, try

```
span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' fill ')][last()]
```